# Did Edit functionality change?

Tags: bug, editing

I'm trying to adjust the tags on the following question:

[Using an unregistered company name](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131183/using-an-unregistered-company-name)

To remove the `Game-Design` tag and add the `Legal` tag.
However, it gives me the error message "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"

I've been able to make tag only edits before, is there something that's change? How should I be making these kind of tag edits?

Comment: Are you trying to edit the whole question or just using the "edit tags" button next to the tags themselves?

Comment: I don't see an "edit tags" button. I think Edit Tags is a rep or mod privilege that skips review.

Comment: Probably, and since you're below the threshold required to edit without review the system probably wants you to make more substantial edits. I don't know if this changed recently or not as a way of heading off a lot of the bad, irrelevant tag edits. You may want to check on MSE.

Comment: Not seeing anything on MSE (StackExchange Meta right?). And I was able to do this as of last week, October 8 to be specific.

Comment: @JoshPetrie I'm assuming you are suggesting, if this is an issue, it's an issue across SE and not just gamedev.  Posted a question to SE Meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285645/has-edit-functionality-changed-i-cannot-edit-just-tags

Comment: Yes, because there's really no reason I can think of that would have localized such a change to GDSE.

Comment: what was the exact question you edited on October 8th to suggest this was previously accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The core functionality of the *Edit* button has not changed, and you *can* make tag-only edits *within reason***.

I have previously encountered situations where I only wished to change a tag, but the edit was "too minimal". That said, I was able to [submit an edit](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/revisions/131300/2) to a question where I only removed the [unityscript](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unityscript) tag<sup>1</sup>. I was required to submit a manual edit description, but once entered, my edit was successfully submitted.

It is difficult to define "too minimal" in regards to a tag-only edit, due to conflicts between the two circumstances, but here are some ideas:

**It *may* involve further consideration, regarding edited characters**

- It can not be a simple count of how many characters the edit changes, as an edit of "legal <strike>game-design</strike>" has a character count of *at least* 16, while "<strike>unityscript</strike>" only has a character count of 11.
- I had considered that only the '*total character sum*' of tags was taken into consideration, but by my count, "legal <strike>game-design</strike>" gives a 'total character sum' change of +6.

**It *may* be an unwritten privilege**

Admittedly, the ability to make tag-only edits might seem insignificant. As a result, it is entirely possible that the ability to do so comes with the provision of *other* privileges, without deliberate mention. If that *is* the case, this would have to be somewhere between the last privileged *you* unlocked ([*View Close Votes*](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) at 250 reputation) and the next privilege *I* can unlock ([*Edit Questions and Answers*](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) at 2,000 reputation). Two particular privileges stand out:

- [*Create Tags*](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) at 300 reputation *may* also yield improved ability to edit tags.
- *[Access Review Queues](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)* at 500 reputation *may* also extend the general ability to edit, including tags.

Either way, nothing is mentioned regarding editing tags. We would need a moderator or higher to comment on whether either of these *could* or *would* be the case.

**It *may* be a user-specific bug**

If it ultimately boils down to a bug, we know that the bug does not affect everybody, or is at least a little more specific than preventing *all* tag-only edits. We *do* know that it is not a recent change, as ultimately, we have seen that tag-only edits have been accepted as recently as within 5 hours of the original post.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Immediately after submitting the tag change, I proof read the question and submitted a more thorough edit. The initial edit was confirmed almost instantly, so both edits appear as separate revisions.</sub>

Comment: It is odd, and all seems to be working now. I'm accepting your answer here, and if I come across the issue again will further update the question on MSE with any info I can gather.